# EventListener arraylength or childElementCount

Tags: javascript, tampermonkey

learning vanilla JS, practicing on serveral pages via Tampermonkey and my own local html/js.
Right now I am playing around with [cookieclicker](http://orteil.dashnet.org/cookieclicker/).
Sometimes a golden Cookie appears randomly on the page. If clicked, it sometimes gives a buff which is increasing the amount of cookies got from the big cookie click.

Goal: If goldenCookie appears (don´t matter how often) click it.
If Buff is active: Click as often as I want onto the bigCookie until the buff is inactive.

I already created this code, which is working.
But with setInterval, of course it´s overlapping and decresing the performance.

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name         GoldenCookie
// @namespace    http://tampermonkey.net/
// @version      1.0
// @description  Intervall check and click golden cookie, if buff quickly "loop"click bigCookie
// @author       ProfDrNoiR
// @match        http://orteil.dashnet.org/cookieclicker/
// @grant        none
// ==/UserScript==

function checkGoldenCookie (){
    if (document.getElementsByClassName("crate enabled buff").length > 0) {
        var Buff = true;
    } else {
        var Buff = false;
        }


if (Buff) {
        var IntervalBigCookie = setInterval(function(){
            document.getElementById("bigCookie").click();
            }, 5)
        }

setTimeout(function(){
    clearInterval(IntervalBigCookie);
    }
           , 1000);

if (document.getElementsByClassName("shimmer").length > 0) {
    document.getElementsByClassName("shimmer")[0].click();

}
}

setInterval(checkGoldenCookie, 20);
```

The random buffs appear under a div class "buffs" and get the class "buff".
The random golden Cookie appears under a div class "shimmers" and get the class "shimmer". So to go away from the

```
setInterval(checkGoldenCookie, 20);
```

and make it better i thought about EventListeners. My research failed at array EventListeners so i thought about a workaround with childElementCount and  started creating this:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name         GoldenCookie
// @namespace    http://tampermonkey.net/
// @version      2.0
// @description  Auto golden Cookie Click and massive Big Cookie Click on Buff
// @author       ProfDrNoiR
// @match        http://orteil.dashnet.org/cookieclicker/
// @grant        none
// ==/UserScript==

document.getElementById("shimmers").addEventListener(
    "onchange", shimmerChange);
console.log("addEventListener shimmers Done");
document.getElementById("buffs").addEventListener(
    "onchange", buffChange);
console.log("addEventListener buffs Done");

function shimmerChange()
    {
        var amtGoldenCookies = document.getElementById("shimmers").childElementCount;
        while (amtGoldenCookies > 0)
        {
            document.getElementsByClassName("shimmer")[0].click();
            amtGoldenCookies = amtGoldenCookies - 1;
            console.log("addEventListener buffs Done")+amtGoldenCookies;
        }
    };


function buffChange()
    {
        var amtBuffs = document.getElementById("buffs").childElementCount;
        if (amtBuffs > 0)
        {
            var buffActive = true;
            console.log("buffActive true");
        } else
        {
            var buffActive = false;
            console.log("buffActive false");
        }

        if (buffActive)
        {
            var IntervalBigCookie = setInterval(function()
            {
                document.getElementById ("bigCookie").click();
                console.log("bigCookie clicked");
            }, 5);
        } else
        {
            clearInterval(IntervalBigCookie);
            console.log("clearInterval bigCookie click");
        }
    };
```

As this is hard to test, I provide you here with a save game from mine, where the goldenCookies appear relative often:

```
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%21END%21
```

As you can see I added the some console.logs, to see how far I come. The eventListeners are added. Also the ChromeDevTools show on the elements the eventListeners.

I hope you can help me and push mit into the right direction.

Comment: A variable declared inside a function is lost when the function completes and runs next time. Meaning your clearInterval does nothing. Try declaring the variable globally and then just assign to it (without `var`).

Comment: @wOxxOm you are right, created now a global var "BigCookieInterval" and call it on the if (buffActive) and "clearInterval(BigCookieInterval);" on false. Problem is: Now it´s clicking all the time without action from the Eventlistener. Also the golden Cookie Click don´t do anything.